# Swift (Playground): Use of unresolved identifier 'addAnimaltoZoo'

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Hi StackOverflow People,

I've recently started learning iOS Development. I have a littl ebit of experience with Java and Python already, but Swift is a completely new language to me.

I was trying to apply the classic example of the Animal Class to understanding the playground environment, syntax, and [logic?].

2 Main Questions:

1. With regards to error (last line in Animal Init) I think I get why I received an error here, but I'm very confused about how to resolve it? Would I have to make something optional? or am I completely misunderstanding the MVC format? I tried to move the method inside the init, but am having a problem with it referencing the Zoo var... if I move the zoo var before the class definition, then I get errors with Animal.
2. Do I have to create a toString type method for classes to print
   something normal in Swift? I tried to do searches, but constantly
   found resources for structs and not for classes... so I'm a little
   confused here too.

Thanks in advance <3

Code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

print("Welcome to the Animal Playground.")

//Simple Animal Class
class Animal {
    var name : String
    var species : String
    var age : Int

    init(name:String, species:String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
        addAnimaltoZoo(animal: self) **//Use of unresolved identifier 'addAnimaltoZoo'**
    }
}

//Everything afterward would be part of the AppController
var zoo = [Int: Animal]()
var animalCounter = 0;

func addAnimaltoZoo(animal: Animal) {
    zoo[animalCounter] = animal
    animalCounter += 1
}

var Tom = Animal(name: "Tom", species: "Cat", age: 105)
var Jerry = Animal(name: "Jerry", species: "Mouse", age: 108)

for (animalID, animalDetails) in zoo {
    print("\(animalID): \(animalDetails)")
}
```

Prints:

```
Welcome to the Animal Playground.
0: __lldb_expr_4.Animal
1: __lldb_expr_4.Animal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have class `class Animal` and are calling `addAnimalToZoo(animal:Animal)` however, it is OUT of the scope of `Animal`. Notice the `{ }` brackets for `class Animal` are CLOSED before `addAnimalToZoo(animal:Animal)` is initialized. Therefore, `class Animal` cannot see this reference. You could, however do this

```
//Everything afterward would be part of the AppController
var zoo = [Int: Animal]()
var animalCounter = 0;

func addAnimaltoZoo(animal: Animal) {
    zoo[animalCounter] = animal
    animalCounter += 1
}

var Tom = Animal(name: "Tom", species: "Cat", age: 105)
var Jerry = Animal(name: "Jerry", species: "Mouse", age: 108)
addAnimalToZoo(animal: Tom)
addAnimalToZoo(animal:Jerry

for (animalID, animalDetails) in zoo {
    print("\(animalID): \(animalDetails)")
}
```

Note: I would keep it like this as `Animal` and `Zoo` are NOT the same, therefore, `addAnimalToZoo(animal:Animal)` should NOT be in the `class Animal`.

Regarding `animalDetails`, I'm not really sure what is going on there or what it is printing. It looks like it is printing `zoo.enumerated()` which you can see from [enumerated() for Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated).

What you should do, if you want to print animal variables, or what I do, maybe there is a better way, is create a method and call it.

```
class Animal {
    var name : String
    var species : String
    var age : Int

    init(name:String, species:String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
    }

    func printAnimalDetails() {
        print("Age: \(self.age) -- Species: \(self.species) -- Name: \(self.name)")
    }
}
```

Then call it

```
for (index, animal) in zoo.enumerated() {
    print("\(index)", terminator: "") //The terminator allows it to NOT create a new line on the next print statement.
    animal.printAnimalDetails()
}
```